# Creating Docker Container for my database

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two questions.

1. If I add the MySQL image in my Dockerfile's `FROM` command, does it
   run the `entrypoint` and `CMD` of the MySQL image? I can't find
   documentation on that.
2. How can I create a reproducible development database container via a
   Dockerfile?

I'm trying to create reproducible development database container. Currently I use the `docker exec` command to import the database, but I would prefer to combine this into one step.

Here are the contents of the Dockerfile that I created.

```
FROM mysql:5.5.44

COPY sql/devdb.sql /root/

CMD mysql -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE < /root/devdb.sql
```

When I go to run it, I get the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I found out that the MySQL server isn't even running, which makes me think none of the parent image's commands are ran?

I found the `CMD` suggestion in the MySQL Docker Registry comments page, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If I add the MySQL image in my Dockerfile's FROM command, does it run the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` of the MySQL image?

yes as long as you do not add your own `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directive in your Dockerfile.

> 2. How can I create a reproducible development database container via a Dockerfile?

What you are missing is understanding *when* [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#run), [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) are executed.

The `RUN` directives are executed à *build time*. When you do `docker build ...`.

The `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives are only executed at *run time*. When you do `docker run` or `docker start`.

With that knowledge, it is now clear why no MySQL server is running at build time. As a result, you cannot import data into the MySQL server at build time.

However, what you can do is to keep the `COPY` directive so that the container to be started will have the sql data ready to import, then also provide your own entrypoint script which will have the responsibility (at run time) to execute the [`/entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/9041eeb49d92368fcbad87dc45957afea0c5662b/5.5/docker-entrypoint.sh) script provided by the MySQL image and then import your sql data.

---

create the following `my-custom-entrypoint.sh` file next to your `Dockerfile`

```
#!/bin/bash

# first things first, call the MySQL image provided entrypoint script
# "$@" is to pass all parameters as they are provided
/entrypoint.sh "$@"

# then import the sql data
mysql -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE < /root/devdb.sql
```

your `Dockerfile` is then

```
FROM mysql:5.5.44

COPY sql/devdb.sql /root/
COPY my-custom-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/my-custom-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomasleveil! I noticed you have `/entrypoint.sh "$@"` but in the Dockerfile, there are no arguments passed to entrypoint. At the same time, `/entrypoint.sh` requires `mysqld` as a parameter.

Do you know why that is? Thanks!

Comment: whatever is given with either the `CMD` instruction in a the Dockerfile or as the positional parameters of the `docker run` command (the ones after the image name) will be passed to the entrypoint as parameters. This applies only if an entrypoint is defined.

Comment: So if I have `echo "$@"` in my `ENTRYPOINT ["/my-custom-entrypoint.sh"]` script, and then run `CMD ["testarg"]` I should see it echo out. Am I understanding that correct? It doesn't seem to be running the parent image's CMD.

Comment: For a test now, my script only contains this:
`/entrypoint.sh "$@"`

And I have the same CMD as the parent Dockerfile (mysql). I'm not sure what's going on, but it doesn't seem to be executing.

Comment: I've put together a test case for you: https://gist.github.com/thomasleveil/b375c65261cbba64be2d which demonstrate the use of `"$@"` in an entrypoint script

Comment: I appreciate the Gist. I used `git clone` to put it in a new directory. Ran the `build` command you specified and then ran `docker run --rm test` and I got this error. 

    docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run --rm test bash
    no such file or directory
    FATA[0001] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 635ecb3f12a923908b468516b522
    9e1d9473f8c41a9fd2b75c74b41a444243fd: [8] System error: no such file or directory

I'm not sure if it's related to boot2docker or not?

> T

Comment: I rebooted my computer just to be on the safe side and I still receive the same error.

Comment: Make sure the .sh files has Unix style end of lines.

Comment: Geez, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks, it worked!

Comment: Ok, I just figured out my main issue through your example. I originally had `ENTRYPOINT /mysql-entrypoint.sh` which doesn't work. After changing it to `ENTRYPOINT ["/mysql-entrypoint.sh"]` it now works. I thought I read somewhere that brackets were only necessary if there were spaces. After looking at the docs, I guess I'm wrong. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It looks like, due to the `exec "$@"` in the MySQL entry point script, that I'll need to unfortunately modify that file.

Comment: I've written a docker container for mysql that simply scans a certain directory for sql scripts and runs them if there are no databases at startup. This makes it very easy to spin up a mysql container with one or more preloaded databases in it. See https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/nota/docker-mysql/ - I can provide some documentation if you'd like.